# Combine multiple module jars into a single one

Tags: java, maven

Now I have a Maven project and here's my project structure:

```
| sound(parent)
| -- sound-service (sub-module)
| -- sound-start (sub-module)
```

In `sound`'s `pom`. I have following:

```
<modules>
    <module>sound-service</module>
    <module>sound-start</module>
</modules>
```

After click clean - compile - package in order, IDEA IntelliJ helps me create two JAR packages for each sub-module. But what I want is a single JAR file with all dependencies and JAR libraries included. I also added the following maven plugin in the pom file of parent root, but I still cannot get one JAR with the whole thing.

```
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
    <archive>
        <manifest>
            <mainClass>com.yct.Application</mainClass>
        </manifest>
    </archive>
    <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
    </descriptorRefs>
</configuration>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>make-assembly</id> 
        <phase>package</phase> 
        <goals>
            <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

Did I miss something? Do I also need to add some other dependencies in `sound`'s `pom`?

Comment: You're looking for a "fat jar" solution - I think, not really played with "modules"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jar-with-dependencies` can help you build a *jar* with the *dependencies*, not *modules*.

Instead of using `<modules></modules>`, try to use `<dependencies></dependencies>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think the recommended way to put together single-jar applications in Maven is to use the shade plugin. In one of my projects, I configure it like this:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <configuration>
            <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/attached-artifact.html -->
            <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
            <shadedClassifierName>standalone</shadedClassifierName>
            <transformers>
                <transformer
                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                    <mainClass>main.class.name.here</mainClass>
                </transformer>
                <transformer
                    implementation="com.github.edwgiz.mavenShadePlugin.log4j2CacheTransformer.PluginsCacheFileTransformer" />
                <transformer
                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                    <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                </transformer>
                <transformer
                    implementation="org.springframework.boot.maven.PropertiesMergingResourceTransformer">
                    <resource>META-INF/spring.factories</resource>
                </transformer>
                <transformer
                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                    <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                </transformer>
                <transformer
                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
            </transformers>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>shade</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.github.edwgiz</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin.log4j2-cachefile-transformer</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
```